# What is the complexity of the following function as a recurrence relation procedure? Can you please explain the steps?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, recurrence

What is the complexity of the following function as a recurrence relation procedure? Can you please explain the steps?

```
void test(int x){

    if(x <=0) return;
    System.out.println(x);
    test(x/2) + test(x/3);

}
```

Comment: Did you try to count the steps the function needs to take for different values of x (for example 1, 2, 3, 10, 15, 20, 30)? Do you notice a pattern?

Answer (score 2):

Inside the function, you have a base case (x<=0), then you have an O(1) operation (the print), and then you recursively call the function.

You get the following function:

T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/3) + O(1)

How do you now derive the O notation from here?

Consider the following image:

[image]

This is the recursive tree of the formula.

The left side divides each time by 2, so height, meaning the number of degrees in the left-most path is log_2(n). That is also the longest path of the three since it's the "slowest". Dividing always only by 2, (and not 3), will arrive at the best case later.

The right-most path is log_3(n). That is also the shortest path of the three since it's the "fastest". Dividing always only by 3, (and not 2), will arrive at the best case sooner.

Now, let's calculate the sum of the values in each degree. In the first degree is clearly 1. In the 2nd degree is smaller than 1. It's clear that for every degree, the sum of values is <=1.

The solution will be the sum of all values of all tree. How do we obtain that? We can multiply the number of degrees by the sum of values in each degree.

We know the worst-case scenario will be **O(log_2(n)*1) = O(log_2(n))**, the best-case scenario **Ω(log_3(n)*1) = Ω(log_3(n))*** . That's the answer.

Comment: Wow, I couldn't ask for a more well explained answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: One more question, since in the algorithm and in the function I'm summing T(n/2) + T(n/3) + O(1) would it be correct to say that, as T(n/2) will always be part of the function, the time complexity is O(log_2(n)) and there will be no bast case of Omega(log_3(n))?

Comment: Yes. You can assume the complexity is O(log_3(n)). More than “best case and worst case”, we may call the two “upper bound and lower bound”. If that makes more sense.

Comment: This is wrong; consider just the row at depth `log_3(n)`, which has `2^log_3(n) = n^c` nodes where `c = 1/log_2(3)`, each of which has `O(1)` work charged to it; the complexity cannot be less than `O(n^c)`.